# Why does using setTimeout work to show chart

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a Single Page App.

In code, I fetch data, and then display it in a chart.

However, there is a timing issue: The data is fetched before the chart has instantiated itself. So the chart ends up showing nothing.

The workaround I found has been to use setTimeout().  But the odd thing is, I set the interval for only 1 milliseconds and chart then displays correctly.

I am guessing that what is really happening is that by using setTimeout(), the current thread is completing the current tasks, and then coming back to the refresh function and then executing. Is that correct?

Is there some other way I should be doing this, as setTimeout() seems to be hackish, and of course, we don't want that.

This is the code that gets the data.

```
async getItemStatusSummary(parentId:number) {
    this.logger.info("getItemStatusSummary()");
    this.itemStatusInfos = await this.statInfoService.getItemStatusInfoByFolderId(parentId, 'ALL');
    this.refreshItemStatusSummaryChart();
}
```

This is the refresh:

```
refreshItemStatusSummaryChart() {

    this.logger.info('RefreshingItemStatusSummaryChart()');
    const chart = $("#itemStatusSummaryChart").data("ejChart");
    if (chart) {
        chart.model.series[0].dataSource = this.itemStatusInfos;
        chart.animate(null);
    }
    else {
        this.logger.info('Chart is null');
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            this.refreshItemStatusSummaryChart();
        }, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct. I've used that "hack" before. Usually, the right way would be passing your function as a callback to be executed once the task (fetching the data) is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand what `setTimeout` is doing behind the scene.

> There is a great talk about this by [Philip Roberts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) that I highly
>   recommend you to listen to, I'll try to explain it shortly in here.

JavaScript is a single threaded engine, meaning that one action is performed at a time, this type of behavior called **stack**, meaning that all tasks will execute in order. What `setTimeout` is actually doing is taking your function passed into it and moving it to the **task queue** which is waiting to the **stack** to clean up from all tasks. Then the **event loop** is taking your function from the **task queue** and passing it to the **stack** again.

This means that calling `setTimeout` will execute your passed function at the end of the stack regardless of the time you've defined it to wait, and that why it is working with the value `0`.

One great solution for you, instead of using `setTimeout` will be to use **Zone.js**.
I won't get in to it in this answer, instead check this [article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/22/understanding-zones.html) about it.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from an Angular 1.x side of things, this became an accepted way/hack to get things to work properly that were asynchronously getting in the way of each other.

In angular is just forced another digest cycle so the thing added to the scope would then show itself. Using a setTimeout of no time was working as well as it was more a matter of showing it further down the execution stack than actually delaying it in any way.

I hope this helps, its a strange thing to deal with but after years of writing angular 1.x apps i just got used to this weird asycn behavior to solve the problems.

Comment: Ok, I had no idea that was common practice. I set the timeout down to zero and it still works fine. Thanks for the input, Will leave it like it is for now.

Comment: Its weird and i went thru several iterations of annoyance with this until i was llike *shrug* ok fine. For what its worth i havent had to make such hacks in any react apps ive been building now for the last couple years.

Comment: Cool! I have been using Aurelia and it's been great.  Haven't tried React, but I have heard much about it.

Comment: This is not wired at all, that's how javascript works with the browser, using webApi's and event loops, check my answer about this

Answer (score 0):

That 's not how you should use `setTimeout`. You need to return a **promise** of your first action & **then** perform your second action.

```
async getItemStatusSummary(parentId:number) {

    this.logger.info("getItemStatusSummary()");

    this.statInfoService.getItemStatusInfoByFolderId(parentId, 'ALL')
                        .then ( response => {
                                this.itemStatusInfos = response;
                                this.refreshItemStatusSummaryChart();
                               });

}
```

As for you second action/method remove the `setTimeout`:

```
refreshItemStatusSummaryChart() {

    this.logger.info('RefreshingItemStatusSummaryChart()');
    const chart = $("#itemStatusSummaryChart").data("ejChart");
    if (chart) {
        chart.model.series[0].dataSource = this.itemStatusInfos;
        chart.animate(null);
    }
    else {
        this.logger.info('Chart is null');
        this.refreshItemStatusSummaryChart();
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice the `await` in the code sample above, which, as far as I understand it, does wrap it in a promise.